# Intermittent IndexError with MySQL and Django running on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, django

Here is what I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 44, in <lambda>
    lambda u: u.is_authenticated,

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 213, in inner
    self._setup()

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 347, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 189, in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 98, in get_user
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):

  File "/.../.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1007, in apply_converters
    value = row[pos]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see, there is none of my code in the stacktrace, all I know is that this code is happening somewhere in a very simple view that gets a queryset and renders it to JSON.

Most of the times it works, *sometimes* this traceback is thrown and the page 500s.

What the hell is going on?

Sometimes I get other weird errors:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

triggered by

```
count += Model.objects.filter(...).count()
```

I've tried to replicate from a shell, but that's not working.

Comment: You're sure there isn't more to the traceback (like "while handling this exception another exception occurred")?

Comment: Please show us the view where you think the error is happening.

Comment: @dirkgroten That's all I'm getting from `@receiver(got_request_exception)`

Comment: @dirkgroten It happens in all sorts of places, completely randomly, for example when calling `Object.objects.filter(foo=bar)`. It seems to be random across *all* such requests, for no particular objects.